# Typescript extends in Pick implementation

Tags: typescript, types

This is a basic implementation of Typescript's `Pick` utility type from [this tuturial](https://learntypescript.dev/09/l3-condition-utility-types)

```
type ObjectWithKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

I undestand what it does, but I find the use of `K extends keyof T` a bit confusing. We want to ensure that K is a member (or union of members) of the union type `keyof T`. It's never going to "extend" it, so why use the `extends` operator here?

Is Typescript lacking an operator and this is the best current option?

Comment: This is the typescript way to say that `K` should be assignable to `keyof T`. For example: `type Result = 'foo' extends 'foo' | 'bar' ? true : false` the `Result` will be `true` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKByAZgezyyggA9gIA7AE3m30KgB9sAjAQwCciB+KYDxNABcUHG2TwIQA

Comment: @AlekseyL it seems back to front, am I going mad? Like it feels like it should be e.g. `'foo' isIn 'foo' | 'bar'`

Comment: @WillJenkins - No, but unions are like that. :-)

Comment: `const test: 'foo' | 'bar' = 'foo'` - will be OK. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I'm really glad you asked this question, it made me really think deeply about something that had been bothering me, which was really useful.

Comment: A value implementation of `Pick` that I wrote a long time ago: https://tsplay.dev/WoJg8m

Comment: @AlekseyL. is this a stupid question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316868/typescript-extends-for-excluding-union-members

Comment: Not stupid at all. _When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type_, meaning the condition will be applied to each union member separately and results will be packed into union. Also pay attention that `extends` is reused in two different features: 1 - generic type constraint and 2 - conditional type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've often been bothered by that reuse of `extends` too, but it's true in a way. The type is `"a" | "b" | "c"`, but you could use something else assignable to that, such as `"a" | "b"`:

```typescript
type ObjectWithKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};

type A = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

type X = ObjectWithKeys<A, "a" | "b">; // Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AdQJbABYGkIgDOAPACoA0UuUEAHsBAHYAmhUA1gQPYBmUpAPigBeKAG8AUFGlQA2gAUoGRlQC6ALn4LVAbgkBfPRNCQoAQRHipMgIabGAVwC2cCACc9MqHHvPXH62lkXxd3PX0JY3BoAA1LeCRUTBx8ImIzSgAiG0yoAB8oTLhMgR0oAHpyqDQuN3ZCIA)

In that sense, you can see `"a" | "b"` as a subtype (more specialized version) of `"a" | "b" | "c"`, just like an object type with *more* properties is a subtype of one with a subset its its properties (which we also represent via `extends`, with interfaces and `class` syntax).

We're (well, okay, **I'm**) used to thinking of subtypes as having "more stuff" than supertypes because I'm used to thinking about object types (where it's true, `{a: number; b: number;}` is a subtype of `{a: number;}`), but with unions it's the other way around, subtypes have *fewer* members than supertypes.

Comment: so `extends` actually means 'is same type or narrows'. Ok, I think I've got it. Cheers.

Comment: @WillJenkins - Yeah, or "is the same as or a subtype of" which is another way of saying [what Aleksey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316418/typescript-extends-in-pick-implementation/70316514?noredirect=1#comment124299553_70316418), "assignable to" (or "assignment compatible").

Comment: Narrows only in case of unions. Nicely put @T.J. Crowder!