# Typescript extends for excluding union members

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the following use of `extends` to remove members from a union type:

```
type RemoveNames<N, K> = N extends K ? never : N

type Names = 'bill' | 'jane' | 'freddy'    
type Bill = RemoveNames<Names, 'jane' | 'freddy'> // type Bill = 'bill'
```

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316418/typescript-extends-in-pick-implementation), `N extends K` was defined to mean that "N is assignable to K", but in this case (on the face of it) `N` is *not* assignable to `K` - only a narrowed version of `N` is assignable to `K`.

How to interpret `extends` in this case? Are the members of `N` iterated over and "filtered" (?) if they're not in `K`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resolving the `Bill` type, TypeScript takes every type of the `Names` union type and resolves the conditional type `N extends K ? never : N`, then builds a final union type with the results:

- Does `'bill'` extend `'jane' | 'freddy'`? No: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `'bill'`
- Does `'jane'` extend `'jane' | 'freddy'`? Yes: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `never`
- Does `'freddy'` extend `'jane' | 'freddy'`? Yes: `N extends K ? never : N` gives `never`

The final type is the union of these three types `'bill' | never | never` which gives `'bill'`.

This behavior is described in the [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) chapter of the docs.

Comment: so it feels like `N extends K` should be thought of as `N' extends K`, where `N'` is one of the members of the union type?

Comment: Yes exactly, as `Names` could be `'bill'` **or** `'jane'` **or** `'freddy'`, the final type is the union of these three possibilities and their result in your conditional type.